# Multiple constructors initializing one object

Tags: java

I was wonder if you can call multiple constructors and initialize one objects values through them. I've been searching for an answer to this but I haven't found one; let me show you some code and thanks for your help in advance:

```
    int MAX_VALUE; // Field variable
    boolean[] elements = new boolean[10000]; // Field variable

    public IntegerSet(int maxValue) {
        this.MAX_VALUE = maxValue;
    }
    public IntegerSet(boolean[] tmp) {
        int i = 0;

        for(i = 0; i < tmp.length; ++i)
            this.elements[i] = tmp[i];

        this.elements = Arrays.copyOf(this.elements, tmp.length);
    }

/*In main:*/

    // I just want to have one object, s1, and I want to be able
    // to access MAX_VALUE and elements by s1.MAX_VALUE and s1.elements
    IntegerSet s1 = new IntegerSet(50); 
    /* SOMETHING that uses second constructor with object s1*/
```

Comment: You can call a constructor from within another constructor by calling `this(args)`

Comment: Why not use a setter?

Comment: Yes but if I'm calling constructor2 from constructor 1, then I need to have constructor2's arguments passed as arguments to constructor1. And I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

You can't call multiple constructors to create one instance of a class. Each call would create a new instance which will be completely different than the other. To set both the `int` field and the array using constructors, the values should be passed to the constructor itself:

```
public IntegerSet(boolean[] tmp, int maxValue) {
    this.MAX_VALUE = maxValue;
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < tmp.length; ++i)
        this.elements[i] = tmp[i];

    this.elements = Arrays.copyOf(this.elements, tmp.length);
}
```

This is equivalent to

```
public IntegerSet(boolean[] tmp, int maxValue) {
    this(maxValue);   // will call the constructor that takes one parameter
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < tmp.length; ++i)
        this.elements[i] = tmp[i];

    this.elements = Arrays.copyOf(this.elements, tmp.length);
}
```

Comment: Yes I totally agree, that's the way I would be doing it, although it's clearly specified that I should use 2 constructors and not 1.

Comment: @Sandkar The only way to use two constructors in your class to create a single instance is to have one constructor call the other. But still you would need two parameters for the first constructor.